# java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe) over a data connection to localhost

Tags: android, streaming, localhost, socketexception

In my Android app I want to read an audio stream and parse its shoutcast metadata.
I got it working using a StreamProxy as in NPR project:
http://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/source/browse/Npr/src/org/npr/android/news/StreamProxy.java?r=e4984187f45c39a54ea6c88f71197762dbe10e72

The problem is that it's not working over a data connection. NPR has got the same issue.

To sum up, this proxy is running as a local web server, making an interface between the app and the remote stream. It's running on localhost 127.0.0.1 with a generated custom port.
When the server is reading the stream data, it replicates it to the app as you can read at line 223 in [StreamProxy](http://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/source/browse/Npr/src/org/npr/android/news/StreamProxy.java?r=e4984187f45c39a54ea6c88f71197762dbe10e72):

```
client.getOutputStream().write(buff, 0, readBytes);
```

However that line produces this exception over a data connection:

```
java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
```

I'm not an expert in sockets and streaming. I don't get what makes a difference between a wifi and a data connection in that case.

Comment: Hi, even I am using a proxy channel to play the streaming. It is throwing this error on some devices. Did you find any solution for this.

Comment: @romain-piel Did you ever figure out what the issue was here?  I'm having the same problem but can't find a solution.

Comment: nope :-/ it's a very weird one. I'm now using a connection in parallel with the streaming. Not ideal but at least it's working in every situations

Comment: @romain-piel Can you please share your solution. My use case is exactly like your and I've been looking for a solution for days.

Comment: @adi and Romain: Does anyone have a solution for this yet? I have a very similar use case and I can't find a way to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

Below are few solutions!

Firstly make sure your client has the same version as the server you're trying to join. If you don't have the same version you can download `MCNostalgia` and use it to downgrade your client.

Update Java

If you don't want to have any incompatibility issues, then I'd encourage you to install the latest Java runtime environment (`jre 7.0_05`). Before you do, it is recommended that you uninstall other previous versions. If your Operating System runs in `32bit` then install the `32bit` (`x86`) version only. If you have `64bit`, install both starting with `64bit` and then `32bit` in this precise order.

Disable un-needed network hosts

`Hamachi` and `Virtual Box` could be one of them. They can slow down or interfere with your connection. Access the network control panel and click on "`modify network cards`" (or something similar). Right click on whichever host you need to disable and then simply click disable.

Disable your firewall

You can access the firewall settings in the control panel and disable it there. If that doesn't work you could try also disabling your router's firewall. If those fail try disabling your anti-virus (these options aren't recommended as hackers can easily infiltrate your computer).

This also works for:

```
> Internal exception: java.net.SocketException: Software  caused
> connection abort: socket write error
```